# How can I justify the text in <a-text> in aframe?

Tags: aframe, webvr, webxr

I want to justify the text rendered in the  tag of a-frame. Is there any way I can do it? align attribute allows only center, left, and right.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a-text is based on [three-bmfont-text](https://github.com/Jam3/three-bmfont-text), which does not support justification. You might want to try [aframe-troika-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-troika-text) instead.

Comment: Yeah, I did find that lib after I posted this. Thanks for the answer though.